# Will firebase hosted websites show up in search results?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm pretty new to firebase hosting and wanted to know if the static websites hosted using firebase will show up in search results with the domain name provided by Firebase. For example the website hosted as 'abc.firebaseapp.com' or 'abc.web.app' will show in the search results after getting a good number of hits or should I go for a custom domain?

Comment: Better get your own domain

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes they will show up in search results. There is not much difference than other hostings you could use beside the free website URLs `abc.firebaseapp.com` and `abc.web.app`.

Your SEO has not much to do if it is hosted on Firebase or elsewhere. Just try to do your best following the Google [instructions](https://search.google.com/search-console/about).

I would also recommend a custom domain because it would improve your overall SEO performance.

Comment: Great answer Tarik. Small clarification: the default subdomains that Firebase providers (*.web.app and *.firebaseapp.com) are not automatically indexed by Google. So if you want Google to only index one of those domains, or maybe only index your custom domain, you can control that by only giving out the domain name that you want to be used/indexed.

Comment: Thx Puf dor the clarification :)